# How to go previous and next visited file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

When navigating to declaration or implementation, I also want to know how to jump back and forth between the last file I viewed.

Is this possible in resharper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> will navigate forwards and backwards between places you've seen. I think they're standard Visual Studio (rather than ReSharper) keybindings.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> will take you the last edit location.

Comment: You can make neat button icons with <kbd> </kbd> - I've done it for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Last few edits for resharper

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Navigating_to_Recent_Edits.html

Lat few files visited

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Navigating_to_Recent_Files.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
CTRL + SHIFT + - => BACK

CTRL + - => NEXT
```

You can read this article about configuring

Link : http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Configuring_ReSharper__Configuring_Keyboard_Shortcuts.html